# Firebase Storage and Read/Unread Feature (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, email, firebase, firebase-storage

My app displays notices and publications that users can view (the text will be stored in firebase storage)
I would like to add a feature where it tells the user whether he or she has read the notices, just like the email app in iOS. Also, it'd be great if you could tell me how to display the number of unread notices in the app.
Thanks

Comment: In your notice add one extra filed named "isRead" when notice created make it `false` by default. now when user click on that notice to open\ read   make that value to `true` and filter your array for  "isRead = false" for count

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked. Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).